# Vulkan API Debug function pointer typecast Error

Tags: c++, struct, types, casting, vulkan

Been stuck with this issue for the past few days. I'm trying to use the Vulkan API's debug layers I've sucessfully fetched the function pointers for the `PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT` and `PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT`.

But when creating the struct to use as an argument for the `vkCreateDebugReportCallback` I'm having issues with the `pfnCallback` part of the struct.

Visual studio is giving me this error when trying to compile, and I have tried typecasting it as follows :

```
dbgReportCreateInfo.pfnCallback = (PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT) debugFunction;
```

and

```
dbgReportCreateInfo.pfnCallback = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT>(debugFunction);
```

which both cause a memory access violation when the `vkCreateDebugReportCallback` function is called.

#### What should work

From the textbook [*Learning Vulkan*](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-vulkan) and the supplied repository the proper declaration for the `PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT pfn` part of the struct should be as shown in their repository [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Vulkan/blob/master/Chapter%2004/DebugVulkan/source/VulkanLED.cpp#L162).

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugFunction(
    VkFlags                    msgFlags, 
    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType, 
    uint64_t                   srcObject, 
    size_t                     location, 
    uint32_t                   msgCode, 
    const char *               layerPrefix, 
    const char *               msg, 
    void *                     userData);
```

#### Vulkan Header file

Which is just as is defined in the Vulkan header file, vulkan.h

```
typdef uint32_t VkBool32;

typedef VkBool32 (VKAPI_PTR *PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT)(
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT                       flags,
    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT                  objectType,
    uint64_t                                    object,
    size_t                                      location,
    int32_t                                     messageCode,
    const char*                                 pLayerPrefix,
    const char*                                 pMessage,
    void*                                       pUserData);


typedef struct VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT {
    VkStructureType                 sType;
    const void*                     pNext;
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT           flags;
    PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT    pfnCallback;
    void*                           pUserData;
} VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT;
```

#### Visual Studio Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Error C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'VkBool32 (__cdecl
>   *)(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT,VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT,uint64_t,std::size_t,uint32_t,const
>   char *,const char *,void *)' to
>   'PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT'    vulkanproject   C:\Users\Alec\workspace\cpp\vulkanproject\source\VulkanLayerAndExtension.cpp    287 Build

#### My code

Full project available in my Github [repository](https://github.com/avlec/vulkanproject)

[VulkanLayerAndExtension.h](https://github.com/avlec/vulkanproject/blob/master/include/VulkanLayerAndExtension.h)

```
class VulkanLayerAndExtension {
    // Some stuff before
    VkResult createDebugReportCallback();
    void destroyDebugReportCallback();
    static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugFunction(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT msgFlags,
        VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType,
        uint64_t srcObject,
        size_t location,
        uint32_t msgCode,
        const char * layerPrefix,
        const char * msg,
        void * userData);

private:
    PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT dbgCreateDebugReportCallback;
    PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT dbgDestroyDebugReportCallback;
    VkDebugReportCallbackEXT debugReportCallback;
public:
    VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT dbgReportCreateInfo = {};
```

[VulkanLayerAndExtension.cpp](https://github.com/avlec/vulkanproject/blob/master/source/VulkanLayerAndExtension.cpp)

```
// stuff before

VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL
VulkanLayerAndExtension::debugFunction(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT msgFlags, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType, uint64_t srcObject, size_t location, uint32_t msgCode, const char * layerPrefix, const char * msg, void * userData)
{
    std::cout << "[VK_DEBUG_REPORT] ";
    if (msgFlags & VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cout << "ERROR";
    }
    else if (msgFlags & VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cout << "WARNING";
    }
    else if (msgFlags & VK_DEBUG_REPORT_INFORMATION_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cout << "INFORMATION";
    }
    else if (msgFlags & VK_DEBUG_REPORT_PERFORMANCE_WARNING_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cout << "PERFORMANCE";
    }
    else if (msgFlags & VK_DEBUG_REPORT_DEBUG_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cout << "DEBUG";
    }
    else {
        return VK_FALSE;
    }
    std::cout << ": [" << layerPrefix << "] Code" << msgCode << ":" << msg << std::endl;
    return VK_TRUE;
}

VkResult VulkanLayerAndExtension::createDebugReportCallback()
{
    VkResult result;

    VulkanApplication * appObj = VulkanApplication::GetInstance();
    VkInstance* instance = &appObj->instanceObj.instance;

    // Get vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT API
    dbgCreateDebugReportCallback = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(*instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (!dbgCreateDebugReportCallback) {
        std::cout << "Error: GetInstanceProcAddr unable to locate vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT function.\n";
        return VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED;
    }
    std::cout << "GetInstanceProcAddr loaded dbgCreateDebugReportCallback function.\n";

    // Get vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT API
    dbgDestroyDebugReportCallback = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(*instance, "vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (!dbgDestroyDebugReportCallback) {
        std::cout << "Error: GetInstanceProcAddr unable to locate vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT function.\n";
        return VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED;
    }
    std::cout << "GetInstanceProcAddr loaded dbgDestroyDebugReportCallback function.\n";

    dbgReportCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    // Type error occurs on this line below
    dbgReportCreateInfo.pfnCallback =   VulkanLayerAndExtension::debugFunction;
    dbgReportCreateInfo.pUserData =     NULL;
    dbgReportCreateInfo.pNext =         NULL;
    dbgReportCreateInfo.flags =         VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
                                        VK_DEBUG_REPORT_PERFORMANCE_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
                                        VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT |
                                        VK_DEBUG_REPORT_DEBUG_BIT_EXT;

    // Create the debug report callback object
    result = dbgCreateDebugReportCallback(*instance, &dbgReportCreateInfo, NULL, &debugReportCallback);
    if (result == VK_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Debug report callback object created successfully.\n";
    }

    return result;
}

void VulkanLayerAndExtension::destroyDebugReportCallback()
{
    VulkanApplication * appObj = VulkanApplication::GetInstance();
    VkInstance & instance = appObj->instanceObj.instance;
    if (debugReportCallback) {
        dbgDestroyDebugReportCallback(instance, debugReportCallback, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Anju!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you casting the function?? You should not! The function already has to be the required type.

I also do debug programmatically in [my example project](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/6e7b4d20474597430ddee65afe566d154ead2b08/ErrorHandling.h#L277), and it works, so lets have it here for comparison:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL genericDebugCallback(
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT msgFlags,
    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType,
    uint64_t srcObject,
    size_t /*location*/,
    int32_t msgCode,
    const char* pLayerPrefix,
    const char* pMsg,
    void* /*pUserData*/
){
    // just print everything
    return VK_FALSE;
}

//// elsewhere
VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT debugCreateInfo{
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CREATE_INFO_EXT,
    nullptr,
    debugAmount,
    genericDebugCallback,
    nullptr
};

VkDebugReportCallbackEXT debug;
VkResult errorCode = vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT( instance, &debugCreateInfo, nullptr, &debug );
RESULT_HANDLER( errorCode, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT" );
```

So scanning your code I see these problems:

1. You are casting function type.
2. `PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT::msgCode` is `int32_t` not `uint32_t`
3. You should probably not return `VK_TRUE` from the callback unless you know what you are doing.
4. Why is there a `*instance` and also `VkInstance&`?? There's no point to it. It is a handle. Use the `VkInstance` directly; no pointers, not dereferencing and no references needed.
5. In `dbgReportCreateInfo.flags` do you really want `VK_DEBUG_REPORT_DEBUG_BIT_EXT`? It is bit of a odd choice considering you are not also accepting `INFO`.

1 and 2 should fix your immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help it's amazing how much trouble 1 letter can cause haha. For 4 I'm following with a textbook and it might be planning to use it differently but yes I could use that instead of pointers. For 5 I have made changes so that I am also accepting info. Thank you so much for the help and advice on the other things as well! :)